# RTKQuery polling with args from store/state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am trying to collect data every 60 seconds, the data I want to collect is keyed by time stamp. Since I only want to collect the data since the last request I am using timestamps as URLSearch params:

```
query: (args: { id: string; lastFetch: string }) => {
        return {
          url: `/dashboard/${args.id}/data?start=${
            args.lastFetch
          }&end=${(new Date()).toJSON()}`,
        };
      },
```

Where to begin the 'lastfetch' value is "1899-12-31T00:00:00.000Z" to get all data before this time.

Once data has been received the last fetch field (Which is stored in the Redux Store) is updated to the end time:

```
dispatch(updateLastFetch({lastFetch: (new Date()).toJSON(), id: args.id}));
```

The time updates in the store as expected. When the polling interval has elapsed the same arg (originally "1899-12-31T00:00:00.000Z") is used and not the newly dispatched value.

The useQuery has the arg as a value from state that I am updating from the useAppSelector hook from where the lastFetch is being updated. This state value updates and prints to the console.

But this also reinitializes the request causing it to happen again.

Is there a way I can access the store directly from the RTKQuery builder to get the lastFetch value to put directly into the params without having to pass it into the UseQuery?

If not what other way is there to do this type of fetching?

Thank you.

I tried adding a skip value if the start and end date were the same (Which would happen after the first request as there was a re-render with the new 'lastFetch' value) but this then stopped the polling.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can access the store directly from the RTKQuery builder to get the lastFetch value to put directly into the params without having to pass it into the UseQuery?

Yes, if you use a `queryFn` you will have access to `getState` through the [arguments of the query function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#queryfn-function-arguments).  Specifically, the second argument `api`.

```
const myApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getData: build.query<Data, string>({
      // The args now can be just the string id instead of an object.
      queryFn: (args, api, extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        // Select the last fetch timestamp from your state.
        const lastFetch = selectLastFetch(api.getState());
        // Call the base query like you did before. 
        return baseQuery({
          url: `/dashboard/${args}/data?start=${
            lastFetch
          }&end=${(new Date()).toJSON()}`,
        });
      },
    }),
  }),
})
```